# How should we interpret $\frac {d}{dt}$?

Tags: derivatives

I've been using derivatives and integrals mechanically for years without really questioning the symbols.  I recently watched some YouTube videos and came to understand that:$$\frac {dx}{dt}$$basically means, for some function, $f(t)=x$, an infinitesimal change in $t$, or $dt$, results in an infinitesimal change in $x$, or $dx$.  The ratio of those two numbers is the derivative, or the instantaneous tangent line of $f(t)$ at $t$.  So far, so good.

So could someone explain how to interpret this:$$\frac {d}{dt}$$I get that the bottom part is an infinitesimal change in $t$, but what is the top part?  And how should I read an expression like $$\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}$$My main confusion is the $d$ part seems to have an existence on it's own without the dimension.

Comment: How do you interpret $'$ on it's own within the expression $f'(x)$?

Comment: I mean, $\frac d{dt}$ usually will be followed by a function $f(t)$, so you can interpret it as change in $f$ over change in $t$. Of course, the proper interpretation of derivatives relies heavily on exterior algebra and isn't particularly illuminating without further mathematical background, so this is a fine way of thinking of it.

Comment: You can interpret them by how they’re defined via limits: $\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$. The functional viewpoint further allows us to define the *operator*, $\frac{d}{dt}$, by a mapping of one function $f$ to another function $f’$ defined by that above limit, whenever it exists. The geometric intuition is in there too—the difference quotient is the slope of the secant connecting $(x,f(x))$ to $(c,f(c))$, which tends to the slope of the (unique) tangent line at $c$ (if it exists) as $x \to c$, so also the interpretations as rates of change over infinitesimally small input changes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{d} {dt}$ is the differential operator that tells you to differentiate with respect to $t$.  As such, $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ means the second derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$.

For comparison, imagine seeing $\ln$ by itself or seeing $\tan$ by itself in the context of an equation -- it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I wouldn‘t say $\log$ or $\tan$ don‘t make sense on their own - these are just functions.